# How to open up console window with multiple columns in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I was wondering, where I can open up console window with multiple columns in Xcode 10.2.1, as displayed below?

[image]

So far, the best I can get is as follow

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define our terms. The Console app (your first screen shot) is an app, different from Xcode, which is also an app. Within the Xcode app, each project window has a "console" which is part of the Debug pane.

The Console app and Xcode can work together, so Xcode doesn't need to do natively what Console already does.

- Console behaves as an extension of your work in Xcode, in the sense that logging messages you send from your app are directed there. Use `os_log` to take advantage of columns and filtering.
- The console within Xcode is just a dumb terminal. You are effectively talking directly to `lldb`. Use `print` to send simple strings; `os_log` works here as well. You can use the Filter field at the bottom to limit what you see if there's too much output. (Note also that console output is saved for later analysis in the Reports navigator.)

Comment: Ok. I thought "Console app" is a child window in XCode app. Apparently I'm wrong.

Comment: I'll add that to my answer.